# Combining SVG, HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an HTML file that looks somehow like this:

```
<html>
 <div id="test"> ... </div>
 <object data="pic.svg" [...]></object>
</html>
```

Inside pic.svg, I have an element, let's say, a circle, and I want to realize something like that:

```
<circle onClick="doSomething()" [...]>
```

Now, in the js function doSomething() (i.e. when someone clicks on the circle) I want to change my "test"-div. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the parent document (and consequently the elements there) from inside the svg like this:

```
var divInParentDocument = window.parent.document.getElementById('test');
```

Here's a (slightly more complex) [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/from-svg-to-parent-html-script.html) showing how to call a function in the parent html document from inside an svg.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the SVG to live in the same DOM as the HTML, best to use an embedded `<svg>` element. It's pretty [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5).

Something like

```
<svg id="svgroot" width="600" height="600"
     version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<script type="text/ecmascript">//<![CDATA[
   function doSomething() {
       document.getElementById('test').appendChild(...);
   }
//]]></script>

<circle onClick="doSomething()" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my svg file is quite large, so I'd like to avoid having the svg code in the HTML file...

Comment: @vauge that's what `xlink` is for. You can just link in an external SVG.